# Cómo puedo rellenar elementos de una lista a partir de un datatable que no siempre tiene el mismo número de filas

Tags: r, lista, bucle-for, txt, exportar

Tengo un datatable con 1 variable que tiene n filas (no siempre va a ser el mismo numero), lo que quiero es exportar a un txt de manera que en cada linea del txt haya 100 observaciones separadas por una coma.

No se si la funcion write.table tiene alguna manera de indicarle que salte de linea cada 100 observaciones, creo que esto seria lo más sencillo.

A mi se me ocurre descompener dentro de una lista, es decir, crear una lista con tantos elementos como necesite para ir metiendo dentro de cada uno las 100 observaciones.
Por ejemplo

Datos

```
dt <- data.table(rep(1:1352))
```

Creo una lista para que me entren todas las observaciones de 100 en 100

```
dt.list <- vector(mode="list", length=ceiling(nrow(dt)/100))
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que me meta del elemento 1 al 100 en el primer elemento de la lista, y a j le sumo 100 para que empiece en el 101 a la siguiente.

```
for (i in 1:length(dt.list)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(dt)){
    dt.list[i] <- dt[j:j+99,]
    j <- j+100
  }
}
```

Mi idea sería luego exportar con write.table.

No me funciona el for que hice, no hace lo que quiero.

Gracias por la ayuda.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Lo más cómodo, es generar un numerador para cada grupo y luego usar `split()` para separar cada grupo en elementos de una lista:

```
lista <- split(dt, ceiling(1:nrow(dt)/100))
```

Verificamos la longitud de cada grupo:

```
sapply(lista, nrow)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
 13  14 
100  52
```

Nota: Por cierto, tus ciclos no están funcionando por que el más interno estas siempre iterando hasta el final: `for(j in 1:nrow(dt)` y en todo caso debería recorrer solo de a 100 elementos

Comment: Gracias Patricio. He añadido list.t <- lapply(lista,transpose) para tener las 100 observaciones en fila para exportar, pero al usar write.table para crear el fichero txt me lo hace en forma columna. Alguna idea?
Gracias por todo, gran trabajo.

Comment: Hola, lo he exportado tras hacer list.t <- lapply(lista,transpose) y si lo exporta a un txt lo unico que al abrir el fichero no me aparecen los 100 en una fila, no se si sera cuestion de la exportacion.

Comment: ¿Quieres transformar una columna en una fila? primero que nada tienes que asegurarte que los valores sean un vector, si lo son puedes usar `rbind()`

Comment: Realmente lo que quiero es que tras hacer la separación de 100 en 100 poder extraer los datos en un txt en filas, y en cada fila las 100 observaciones. Por eso mi idea de ponerlo en filas.